# Get value from another jframe

Tags: java, jframe

I have a jframe1 with a jtextfield and a button.

When the button is pressed, another jframe2 pops up with several jtextfields. Then the user will input values and the program will sum it all up.

What I want is for the total found on jframe2 to be given to jframe1 when jframe2 is closed.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to do so. For example, you could...

- Put a reference to the JTextField into the constructor of your 2nd JFrame, allowing that one to set text
- Let the 1st JFrame add a listener to the 2nd JFrame, which then fires it when the calculation is done, which then leads to the updating of the JTextField.
- Add a private variable on the 2nd JFrame plus a public getter and then let the first one ask for the value after the 2nd one has been closed. I would use a JDialog for this, though, as it allows you to make it modal (in other words, lets the first JFrame wait for the JDialog to close).